# Twitter api search geocode makes issues

Tags: twitter

For me

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?geocode=9.98%2C76.28%2C5km

returns tweets

but for

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?geocode=9.98%2C76.28%2C15km

returns none

For the second the radius is increased to 15km

Why it is not working? I tried it on 
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console

Comment: geocoded search is quite buggy in twitter's API, and the issues aren't getting solved. Log in to https://dev.twitter.com, go to the REST API v1V1  forum and search for "geocode search", you'll get many results. cf. https://twittercommunity.com/t/does-the-twitter-search-api-have-a-max-radius-for-its-geocode-parameter/12947 and https://twittercommunity.com/t/geocode-search-results-fall-out-of-specified-radius/7816

Comment: had some success on that thread?

Answer (score 3):

Some people (including myself) have started experiencing issues with existing geo-related searches from approximately 2014-11-20 23:00 UTC. Perhaps it relates to your problem.

Looks like Twitter developers have been aware of this issue for at least last four days and are working on it. There is no ETA though, last response from Twitter published 12 hours ago  says:

> ...we are aware of the issue and working to resolve it, but it may be a few days. We apologise for the disruption to your applications, and appreciate your patience. We're hopeful that we can get a fix deployed soon, but some things take time

Please see these discussions for more details:

- [1] Search API returning (very) sparse geocode results: https://twittercommunity.com/t/search-api-returning-very-sparse-geocode-results/27998
- [2] Twitter Advanced Search Not Working: https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-advanced-search-not-working/28114